# Angular7/Display list of fieldsets from array grouped by specific field

Tags: html, angular, typescript

typescript has an array like :

'let list = [ { name: 'sdd', ident: 'Fe', groupId: 3 }, { name: 'sss', ident: 'Cu', groupId : 0 }, { name: '1050 AJ', ident: 'Mn', groupId: 3 }, { name: 'X332.0 AC', ident: 'V', groupId: 3 }, { name: 'X4002', ident: 'Mm', groupId : 0 }, { name: 'X400s', ident: 'cn', groupId : 4 }, { name: 'X4002 z', ident: 'xx', groupId : 4 }, ];'

Using Angular & html : I wanna group them with groupId field and display in fieldset with the first name of list and if groupId == 0 it should have it's own fieldset like :

sdd:

ident: 'Fe'

ident: 'Mn'

ident: 'V'

==============

sss:

ident: 'Cu'

==============

X4002:

ident: 'Mm

==============

X400s:

ident: 'cn'

ident: 'xx'

==============

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new object to do what you are trying to achieve and then can display this using loops in your Angular as you desire.

```js
let list = [ { name: 'sdd', ident: 'Fe', groupId: 3 },
 { name: 'sss', ident: 'Cu', groupId : 0 },
  { name: '1050 AJ', ident: 'Mn', groupId: 3 },
   { name: 'X332.0 AC', ident: 'V', groupId: 3 },
    { name: 'X4002', ident: 'Mm', groupId : 0 },
   { name: 'X400s', ident: 'cn', groupId : 4 },
   { name: 'X4002 z', ident: 'xx', groupId : 4 }, ];

const formattedlist = {};
formattedlist[0] = [];
for(let i=0;i<list.length;i++){
    let obj = {};
    if(list[i].groupId===0){

        obj[list[i].name] = {ident: list[i].ident};

        formattedlist[0].push(obj);
    }
    else{
        if(formattedlist[list[i].groupId] === undefined){
            formattedlist[list[i].groupId] = {};
            formattedlist[list[i].groupId].name = list[i].name;
            formattedlist[list[i].groupId].ident = [list[i].ident];            
        }
        else{
            formattedlist[list[i].groupId]['ident'].push(list[i].ident);             
        }
    }
}

console.log(formattedlist);
```